# how to speed up docpad rendering?

Tags: docpad

I am changing only a couple of pages but docpad seems to render everything again. I'm not using any fancy plugins or dynamic components - just the basic ghost template. Are there some techniques to make less pages render?

maybe its something to do with the timestamp format in the docpad.coffee ?

```
moment = require('moment')
docpadConfig = {
  templateData:
    vars:
      appserver: 'http://xxx'
    site:
      title: 'Pocket Tutor'
      tagline: 'English language chat tutor'
      description: 'Learn english by chatting'
      logo: '/uploads/images/corpid/comiceng/96/logo-96.png'
      url: 'http://app:9005'
      cover: '/img/cover.jpg'
      navigation: [
        {
          name: 'Home',
          href: '/',
          section: 'home'
        },
        {
          name: 'About',
          href: '/about.html',
          section: 'about'
        },
        {
          name: 'Lessons',
          href: '/tags/lessons.html',
          section: 'tag-lessons'
        },
        {
          name: 'Grammar',
          href: '/tags/grammar.html',
          section: 'tag-grammar'
        }
        {
          name: 'Teachers',
          href: '/tags/tech.html',
          section: 'tag-tech'
        },

      ]
    author:
      name: 'Rikai Labs'
      img: ''
      url: 'http://rikai.co'
      website: 'http://RIKAI.co'
      location: 'space',
      bio: 'we build chat apps'
    getPreparedTitle: -> if @document.title then "#{@document.title} | #{@site.title}" else @site.title
    getDescription: -> if @document.description then "#{@document.description} | #{@site.description}" else @site.description
    bodyClass: -> if @document.isPost then "post-template" else "home-template"
    masthead: (d) ->
      d = d || @document
      if d.cover then d.cover else @site.cover
    isCurrent: (l) ->
      if @document.section is l.section  then ' nav-current'
      else if @document.url is l.href then ' nav-current'
      else ''
    excerpt: (p,w) ->
      w = w || 26
      if p.excerpt then p.excerpt else p.content.replace(/<%.+%>/gi, '').split(' ').slice(0, w).join(' ')
    encode: (s) -> encodeURIComponent(s)
    slug: (s) -> return s.toLowerCase().replace(' ', '-')
    currentYear: -> new Date().getFullYear()
    time: (ts, format) ->
      format = format || 'MMMM DO, YYYY'
      ts = new Date(ts) || new Date()
      moment(ts).format(format)
  collections:
    posts: ->
      @getCollection("html").findAllLive({active:true, isPost: true, isPagedAuto: {$ne: true}}, {postDate: -1}).on "add", (model) ->
        model.setMetaDefaults({layout:"post"})
  plugins:
    tags:
      extension: '.html'
      injectDocumentHelper: (doc) ->
        doc.setMeta { layout: 'tag' }
    rss:
      default:
        collection: 'posts'
        url: '/rss.xml'
    marked:
      gfm: true

  environments:  # default
    development:  # default
        # Always refresh from server
      maxAge: false  # default
      # Only do these if we are running standalone via the `docpad` executable
      checkVersion: process.argv.length >= 2 and /docpad$/.test(process.argv[1])  # default
      welcome: process.argv.length >= 2 and /docpad$/.test(process.argv[1])  # default
      prompts: process.argv.length >= 2 and /docpad$/.test(process.argv[1])  # default

      # Listen to port 9005 on the development environment
      port: 9005  # example
    production:
      port: 9005
      maxAge: false  # default

}

module.exports = docpadConfig
```

update: stubbing out the date and time methods

```
time: -> 'time'
currentYear: -> 'year'
```

gives a little speed up but still making one edit to one file gives info:

```
Generated 40/150 files in 7.364 seconds
```

update2: added

```
standalone: true
```

to some pages to test, but still takes 
info: Generated 40/150 files in 7.252 seconds

so even a single standalone page triggers a bunch of other stuff.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to handle the Docpad regeneration process manually. To do this you need to turn off Docpad's watch. That is, run Docpad with the `docpad server` command. What will happen here is that it doesn't matter how many times you edit a document it will not be loaded into the docpad collection. You will then have to load any updates manually. That is, have some code to load the document.

```
model = @docpad.getCollection('posts').findOne({someValue: someValue})
model.load()
```

Following that trigger the regeneration.

```
 @docpad.action 'generate', reset: false, (err) ->
     if err
         @docpad.log "warn", "GENERATE ERROR"
```

This is what I do in my [posteditor plugin](https://github.com/SteveMcArthur/docpad-plugin-posteditor)

I suspect this is not really what you are asking for but it does give you full control over the regeneration process.